# Converting mono image bitmap into 1D C array of 8 bit integers

Tags: python, bitmap

To clarify the title, I need to convert, say,

```
"00011111111111110000111111111111
00101111111111110000111111111111
00111111111111110000111111111111
01001111111111110000111111111111
01011111111111110000111111111111
01101111111111110000111111111111
01111111111111110000111111111111
10001111111111110000111111111111"
```

into

```
0b00011111,
0b00101111,
0b00111111,
0b01001111,
0b01011111,
0b01101111,
0b01111111,
0b10001111,

0b11111111,
0b11111111,
0b11111111,
0b11111111,
0b11111111,
0b11111111,
0b11111111,
0b11111111,

...
```

Each 8x8 block of binary is converted into a C array in the format shown. In the actual data I'm operating on, the bitmap dimensions are 128, 48, (width, height), so you can't assume that the bitmap is 8 high. (otherwise I wouldn't be asking this and it would be trivial to do)

This is my current code:

```
# input_str is a (very long) string of binary representation of a bitmap of height 48, width 128.
# I have removed it here as it is irrelevant other than its dimensions.

# I am aware that this code is a mess, but this is just a quick script that I'm only using to 
# automate this task once, as I would rather not sit at my desk for 6 hours sorting out 8x8 blocks 
# of binary from a very long string.

input_str = ""
pass_0 = ""
output_str = ""

IMG_WIDTH = 128
IMG_HEIGHT = 48

BLOCK_SIZE = 8

# Split the bitmap into lines on each 128th index
for i in range(len(input_str)):
    pass_0 += input_str[i]
    if (i % IMG_WIDTH == 0):
        pass_0 += "\n"

# Interate through the lines and get an X block index and a Y block index

blockIndexX = 0
blockIndexY = 0

y = 0
for line in iter(pass_0.splitlines()):
    if (y % BLOCK_SIZE == 0):
        blockIndexY += 1
        
    for x in range(len(line)):
        if (x % BLOCK_SIZE == 0):
            blockIndexX += 1

            blockIndex = (blockIndexX * 6) + blockIndexY

            # And I have no idea how to continue here. 
                
    
    y += 1
    blockIndexX = 0
    

print(output_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out a (very hacky) way of doing it, which is to reformat my input bitmap into a 8x768 image, "stretching out" the 8x8 blocks, making it (somewhat) trivial to parse into the 8x8 blocks. In that format, this bit of (very janky and hacky) code works:

```
# Data omitted for readability reasons

line0 = ""
line1 = ""
line2 = ""
line3 = ""
line4 = ""
line5 = ""
line6 = ""
line7 = ""

blocks = []

for i in range(96):
    blocks.append([])

for i in range(len(line0)):
    character = line0[i]

    if (i % 8 == 0):
        blockIndex = round(i / 8)

        lineSplit = []
        for i in range(0, len(line0), 8):
            lineSplit.append(line0[i : i + 8])


        blocks[blockIndex].append("0b" + lineSplit[blockIndex] + ",")

for i in range(len(line1)):
    character = line1[i]

    if (i % 8 == 0):
        blockIndex = round(i / 8)

        lineSplit = []
        for i in range(0, len(line1), 8):
            lineSplit.append(line1[i : i + 8])


        blocks[blockIndex].append("0b" + lineSplit[blockIndex] + ",")

for i in range(len(line2)):
    character = line2[i]

    if (i % 8 == 0):
        blockIndex = round(i / 8)

        lineSplit = []
        for i in range(0, len(line2), 8):
            lineSplit.append(line2[i : i + 8])


        blocks[blockIndex].append("0b" + lineSplit[blockIndex] + ",")

for i in range(len(line3)):
    character = line3[i]

    if (i % 8 == 0):
        blockIndex = round(i / 8)

        lineSplit = []
        for i in range(0, len(line3), 8):
            lineSplit.append(line3[i : i + 8])


        blocks[blockIndex].append("0b" + lineSplit[blockIndex] + ",")

for i in range(len(line4)):
    character = line4[i]

    if (i % 8 == 0):
        blockIndex = round(i / 8)

        lineSplit = []
        for i in range(0, len(line4), 8):
            lineSplit.append(line4[i : i + 8])


        blocks[blockIndex].append("0b" + lineSplit[blockIndex] + ",")

for i in range(len(line5)):
    character = line5[i]

    if (i % 8 == 0):
        blockIndex = round(i / 8)

        lineSplit = []
        for i in range(0, len(line5), 8):
            lineSplit.append(line5[i : i + 8])


        blocks[blockIndex].append("0b" + lineSplit[blockIndex] + ",")

for i in range(len(line6)):
    character = line6[i]

    if (i % 8 == 0):
        blockIndex = round(i / 8)

        lineSplit = []
        for i in range(0, len(line6), 8):
            lineSplit.append(line6[i : i + 8])


        blocks[blockIndex].append("0b" + lineSplit[blockIndex] + ",")

for i in range(len(line7)):
    character = line7[i]

    if (i % 8 == 0):
        blockIndex = round(i / 8)

        lineSplit = []
        for i in range(0, len(line7), 8):
            lineSplit.append(line7[i : i + 8])


        blocks[blockIndex].append("0b" + lineSplit[blockIndex] + ",")


for k in range(len(blocks)):
    for i in range(len(blocks[k])):
        if (i == 0):
            print(blocks[k][i])
        else:
            print(blocks[k][i])
```

Now, I feel that I should say this: If you're a person coming across this trying to do the same thing I am, please *do not* use this bit of code. Just use a for loop and a list, not this janky hacked together mess.